# Gluon 4.x.x artifacts not in the Nexus repo?

Tags: java, gluon, gluon-mobile, gluon-desktop

Upgrading my project to Gluon Charm 4.3.0 involved updating the dependencies in build.gradle. According to the docs I need to upgrade all 4 charm dependencies; the base and the three platform related ones.
http://docs.gluonhq.com/charm/4.3.0/#_adding_gluon_mobile_to_an_existing_project

When I try to compile I get an "could not resolve all dependencies", and indeed, if I take a peek in the Nexus repo mentioned in the documentation I do see a 4.3.0 for the base, but all the platform based artifact only go as high as 3.*.*. 
http://nexus.gluonhq.com/nexus/content/repositories/releases/com/gluonhq/charm/
http://nexus.gluonhq.com/nexus/content/repositories/releases/com/gluonhq/charm-android/

Has the repo moved or something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right about one thing: the Charm 4+ platform dependencies are not there.

The problem is a bug in the document you linked, as the section 2.5.8 is no longer valid: if you keep on reading until chapter 8 ([migration guide](http://docs.gluonhq.com/charm/4.3.0/#_migration_guide_to_gluon_mobile_4)) you'll see this:

> Gluon Mobile 4 requires only one dependency declaration instead of the four declarations that were needed previously. That will include the dependencies to Charm Glisten and Gluon Connect.

So all you need now is this single Charm dependency:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.gluonhq:charm:4.3.0'
}
```

and this:

```
jfxmobile {
    downConfig {
        version '3.2.0'
        plugins 'display', 'lifecycle', 'statusbar', 'storage'
    }
    android { ... }
}
```

as for the required Charm Down plugins.

Also have a look at the [code changes](http://docs.gluonhq.com/charm/4.3.0/#_code_changes) in Charm Down.

If you create a new project with the Gluon IDE plugin you'll see how the new `build.gradle` file will look like.

Comment: 8.1.2 was such a small paragraph, I apparently skipped over it (because I do have the downConfig in there and all the required code changes).

Comment: Anyway the docs are inconsistent, I've filed an issue to fix that misleading part.

Comment: Great. Thanks. Haven't solved the duplicate zip entry issue when packaging for Android yet?

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: If you include jfxtras-labs, it will include jfxtras-common through two paths (via all->controls and all->fxml), that will give a 'duplicate zip entry' error.

Comment: You can't add duplicate jars, you need to exclude them or just pick one. If you create a new question I can have a look.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/132611/discussion-between-tbeernot-and-jose-pereda).